Help designing a grid builder system with incremental placement
I am currently designing a grid building system for a game and am trying to implement the ability to place objects at different increments (if the grid cells are spaced one unit apart by default, then I would like the ability to place objects by units of 0.5, 0.1 etcetera).
Currently I have a two dimensional array of "Cell" objects, and I convert their position in the grid to world space when visualising the grid and its objects. I don't want to manually place the objects because the all my maths and logic for things like rotation and collision are done on the 2D array and the actual placement just reflects its state.
My initial idea was to create enough cells to satisfy the smallest increment value I had set, however this meant I was generating millions of cells which is slow and I'm sure very inefficient.
If any one has any good ideas or has tackled something similar to this then any advice would be highly appreciated

Does this system need to interact with mobile units, or does the game contain only immobile structures?

@TimC Hi it will just be immobile structures, essentially like a base builder / house builder

Have you looked into using something like a binary space partition or quadtree?

Quadtrees

My initial idea was to create enough cells to satisfy the smallest increment value I had set, however this meant I was generating millions of cells which is slow and I'm sure very inefficient.

Your initial idea is on the right track - however, you don't need to create every cell right away. If a large chunk is empty (or all filled with the same thing), it can be compressed to a single value.
The data structure to use is called a Quadtree. Here's how it works:

A cell is a square whose side length is a power of 2.
A cell can either be all empty, all filled (with the same thing), or subdivided into four quadrants (each of which has 1/2 its side length).
Each quadrant of a subdivided cell is another cell.

An empty world can be represented by a single empty cell, whose size is the size of the world. If an object is added to the world somewhere in the top left quadrant, then that quadrant subdivides. Three of its sub-cells remain fully empty, while the top left sub-cell subdivides again - as many times as necessary until the object that was added fills complete cells.
Speed Considerations
Quadtrees will solve your memory problem of how to fit the entire map - but when it comes time to use it, it can cause some speed problems if you aren't careful. Sampling a cell from a quadtree is O(log(n)), while sampling from an array is O(1). This means that reading-order iteration (starting at the top left of the screen and then scan left-to-right, top-to-bottom) will be slower than you expect, and other algorithms may be required.
This next section is going to be speculative on my part - I've used Quadtrees for file compression before, but not for real-time logic.
Drawing to the Screen
For drawing to the screen, the algorithm I would use is as follows:

Create an "open list" of points to sample, and a "draw list" of rectangles.
Add the point corresponding to the top left pixel of the screen to the open list.
While the open list is not empty, pop from it (call it samplePoint)
If samplePoint has already been drawn or is off screen, go back to step 3 and try again until the list is empty.
Sample samplePoint from the quadtree; call the resulting cell's contents fill and its bottom right corner bottomRight.
Add a rectangle to the draw list, with top left corner samplePoint and bottom right corner bottomRight, and whose value is fill`.
Add a new point to the open list below the rectangle which was evaluated: (samplePoint.x, bottomRight.y + epsilon). Epsilon is the size of the smallest possible partitioning.
Add another new point to the open list to the right of the rectangle which was evaluated: (bottomRight.x + epsilon, samplePoint.y).
Go back to step 3.

If I've done my math right, then when the open list is empty, you should have a draw list with non-overlapping rectangles which completely spans the screen. If you're in a game engine like Unity or Unreal, then you can point a camera at those rectangles and you're good to go. If you're writing your own graphics logic from scratch, you'll have to clip the rectangles to the screen (some of them might be hanging off the bottom or right edges otherwise), draw quads for them, and then ship them to the GPU to be drawn.
Simulation
Presumably, your structures are part of a game and don't just sit there on the map. My recommendation is to keep a separate list of simulation objects and process them by enumerating over that list instead of enumerating over the map. For example, if your builder contains a power grid, you might have a step in your Logic Update loop where you tally up power production and consumption to determine if the network has enough power - you'd do that by enumerating over a list of consumers and producers, not by enumerating over the map to check if each cell uses power.
